# How to center content in webView Android ?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to load image in webView Android. The image size is 320x50 and same for the webView size, but the image is not in center, and I don't understand why.

> [image]

Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm stupid, i have just add <body style=\"margin:0 auto;text-align:center;>...... </body>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView); 
webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Comment: webView.loadData("<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}</style></head><body>"+arrayListAds.get(0).getUrl()+"</body></html>", "text/html", "utf8");

Comment: setDefaultZoom is now deprecated. Refer to this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493567/webview-setdefaultzoom-deprecated