# WebView setDefaultZoom deprecated

Tags: android, webview

Here is the code for setting the default zoom in webview

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

to be working but old. The `setDefaultZoom`value is deprecated, anyone know what the new code is?

Sorry if I'm writing in unprofessional terms and with poor English.

As always, Thanks in advance :)
Regards Ole

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultZoom(android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

This help you to remove setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR).

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported at all anymore. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDefaultZoom(android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity)